# linux kill command -9 vs -15

Tags: linux, bash, process

I have a process that i would like to kill and then restart a service. Someone has written a code to kill the process by writing the following set of scripts

```
ps -ef |grep "process_name" | awk '{print "kill -15 " $2}'> /projects/test/kill.sh
#run the kill script
/projects/test/kill.sh
```

and then again

```
ps -ef |grep "process_name" | awk '{print "kill -9 " $2}'> /projects/test/kill.sh
#run the kill script
/projects/test/kill.sh

#finally
service restart command here     
# the problem here is that service does not restart properly sometimes, 
as it thinks that process is still running.
```

As i understand kill -15 gracefully kills the process. But then right away they have the kill -9 as well. 
So if a process was getting killed in the first command, what happens when kill -9 is also run on the same process? Or will the ps -ef even list out that process since it has been marked for kill?

Thanks!

Comment: Strictly speaking, `kill -15` does not kill the process. It asks the operating system to send signal 15 to the process; how the process responds to the signal is up to the process itself. `kill -9`, on the other hand, does not cause signal 9 to be sent; it requests the OS to simply *end* the process immediately, without any warning. The process simply ceases to be.

Comment: If a process doesn't catch the `-15` or code for it at all, the default is for the signal to just percolate back up to the OS, which will then terminate it after all - yes?

Answer (score 9):

You are correct that `kill -15` is to *gracefully* kill a process. But, killing a process is something that happens instantaneously.  So the program above is going to check for `pid`, attempting to kill it gracefully .. If the `kill -15` *fails* --  The `kill -9` is performed.  The way it knows that `kill -15` failed, is the `grep` command.  If `kill -15` was successful, that `pid` should not exist any longer, making the following `grep` return empty.

So really, `kill -9` only runs if `kill -15` failed to gracefully stop the program.  The problem with this approach, is that sometimes gracefully stopping a process can take some time depending on the program.  So IMHO there needs to be a wait period or a `sleep` for a few seconds to allow `kill -15` to attempt to gracefully stop the process ..  Most assuredly with the approach above, `kill -9` is almost always invoked since the script doesn't allow much time for the process to be shut down properly.  In the event that `kill -15` is still processing, `kill -9` will just override and instantly stop the process.

Comment: Yes, thats what i am thinking...introduce a wait of maybe 20 seconds or so....What i was unsure is if the process was still getting killed then whether kill -9 will override or not..thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Sometimes the `TERM` signal triggers steps that take a few seconds. How long you should wait is a matter of situation and debate, but there *should* be some consideration of it.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the option to refactor, you can use `/proc/$PID` as a more efficient way to detect if a process is running.

```
stopSvc() { local svc=$1
  read x pid x < <( ps -fu "$App_user" | grep -E " ($App_baseDIR/$1/|)$svc.jar$" ||: )
  local -i starting="$(date +%s)" # linux epoch timestamp in seconds
  while [[ -d "/proc/$pid" ]]
  do ps -fp "$pid"
     kill -term "$pid"
     if (( ( $(date +%s) - starting ) < 20 )) # been trying for less than 20s
     then sleep 2
          date
     else echo "$svc is hung - using a hard stop"
          kill -KILL "$pid"
          break
     fi
  done
  sleep 2
  [[ -d "/proc/$pid" ]] && return 1 || return 0  # flip the return
}
```

Basically, the `kill -15` is a `term` signal, which the process could catch to trigger a graceful shutdown, closing pipes, sockets, & files, cleaning up temp space, etc, so to be useful it should give some time. The `-9` is a `kill` and can't be caught. It's the **Big Hammer** that you use to squish the jobs that are misbehaving, and should be reserved for those cases.

You are totally right, this makes little sense. If you're going to use the `-9` so soon, might as well skip the careless attempt at better practice and just remove the `-15`.