# If I use kill -9 for the SpringBoot project, what will happen to its asyn threads

Tags: spring-boot

If I use kill -9 for the SpringBoot project, what will happen to its async(@Async) threads?
and what about kill -15?

Will it wait for the async task to terminate?
If it is my custom thread(pool), what will happen to those threads?
Where is the source code implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, all threads exist in the same address space as the process in which they were spawned. So even your async threads will be killed (they share the same pid). More info [here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364660/are-threads-implemented-as-processes-on-linux)

The difference between kill -9 and -15 is given in good detail [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55796667/linux-kill-command-9-vs-15/55796920)

Comment: Will it wait for the thread execution to complete if i use kill -15?

Comment: In a way yes. It should ideally wait for the threads to finish execution. However, in case when a thread has timed out or taking too long to finish execution, kill -15 may take too long to kill those threads. For such situations, a kill -9 signal should be sent after say x seconds if kill -15 failed to do the job.