# ps(bash) command in ci pipeline

Tags: bash, continuous-integration

I have a code in ci pipeline:

```
  after_script:
    - echo "killing ssh-agent"
    - PID=$(cat /tmp/agent-{$CI_JOB_ID})
    - ps aux | grep ssh-agent
    - if [ $(ps aux | grep ssh-agent | awk '{print $2}') -eq $PID ]; then kill -9 $(echo $PID); else echo 'there is no pid'; fi
    - kill -9 $(echo $PID)
    - echo "PID" $PID "is killed"
```

when I execute pipeline I get this output:

```
$ ps aux | grep ssh-agent
sh: line 137: ps: command not found
```

how can I return all service IDs and kill this one which I need

Comment: Try `pkill -9 ssh-agent` See [`pkill`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)

Comment: Issue is not about process kill, it is about listing the processes. Command "ps" was not found

Comment: I have more other ssh-agent processes, i need to kill exact one from CI_JOB_ID, that is why i cant use process name

Comment: `ps` (and `pkill`, btw) are in the package `procps` (in Debian/Ubuntu). Just install it: `apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps`

Comment: Peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55796667/linux-kill-command-9-vs-15/55799581#55799581 - might help. YMMV.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git, and everything to do with whatever CI systems you're using. The system you're using (whatever it is) doesn't have a `ps` command, or has it in some nonstandard location, or has some nonstandard `PATH` setting, or something along these lines. (Most likely you're getting a Docker container or a VM in which `ps` simply isn't installed.)